# Is it possible that binlog thread fails?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, binlog

I was reading about how to create a primary-replica system and I want to do it in production.
But based on [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-threads/#binary-log-dump-threads-and-the-shutdown-process), I realized that binlog thread could fail and data would be lost.

I didn't find anything useful about the topic, but is there anyway to find out if any data is lost?

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page is a bit of an overzealous. I'll correct this soon.

Data isn't "lost". It's just that when the slaves shut down, they have to stop replicating at some point. As soon as the master is restarted, the slaves will reconnect and resume from where they stopped. No data is lost.

MariaDB replication isn't synchronous, and all this "semisync" doesn't really make it so. If you disconnect all slaves and then commit a transaction, and then throw the master server in the garbage bin without allowing slaves to ever see it again, then yes, your last transaction will not be replicated and will be "lost".

Words from Kristian Nielsen produced with permission.

Comment: Thank you! So based on your answer, it's not possible for binlog thread that fails before some transaction happens? This article explains my question better: https://jfg-mysql.blogspot.com/2018/11/master-replication-crash-safety-part-2-lagging-slaves.html

Comment: An article can mean many questions. The replica -> primary binlog thread can fails, and without the safety of `sync_binlog=1` (sorry Jeff, still not default), a reconnection may not recover the position if indeed the primary fails fatally during shutdown. If you are doing a shutdown to make the replica a primary, `SHUTDOWN WAIT FOR ALL REPLICA` or some equally reliable prevention of writes should be done.

Comment: Thank you @danblack!